# "Undefined method where" error in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have spent the last day trying different things and searching the internet on the answer but I am just plain stuck.

I have a rails app (4.0) which logs PB's made in the gym for different lifts.

I would like to display the highest weight for 1 rep, 3 reps and 5 reps.

My controller looks like this.

```
@history = current_user.workouts.order("weight DESC","reps DESC").group_by(&:lift)
```

The code in my view is then as follows...

```
<% @history.each do | lift, workout | %>
  <% name = lift[lift].downcase.gsub(/[ &]/,'') %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to lift[lift], send("workouts_lift_#{name}_path") %></td>
    <td><%= workout.where(:reps => 1).max_by(&:weight).weight %> kg</td>
    <td><%=  workout.where(:reps => 3).max_by(&:weight).weight %> kg</td>
    <td><%=  workout.where(:reps => 5).max_by(&:weight).weight %> kg</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I keep getting a error for the where method. I'm unclear as to what the problem is as I can get it to work in the rails console using

```
user.workouts.where(:reps=> 1).where(:lift => "Snatch")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, the `workout` variable that is yielded in the `each` block is an instance of the `Workout` class, not the class itself. ActiveRecord query methods such as `where` are only available on classes or relationships, hence the error. Without knowing the underlying architecture of your models and relationships, it's hard to say exactly what you can do to fix it though.

Comment: ah that makes sense, hence why i can do it just fine in the console. 

The architecture is not very complicated though. A User has many Workouts and a Workout belongs to a user.

Do you need anymore info???

Comment: It looks like `workout` is just an array so you should be able to use [Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) instead of `where` to find the workouts where reps == 1, 3, or 5.